# How do you save MATLAB handles in workspace>

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I am writing code for image registration and I would like to save the fixed Image (handles.imgFixed) and moving Image (handles.imgMoving) into the MATLAB workspace. This way I plan to use evalin to bring those variables back into the MATLAB GUI to do further analysis. Here is my code from GUI:

```
function uploadFixed_Callback(hObject, ~ , handles)
% hObject    handle to uploadFixed (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
[filename, pathname] = uigetfile({'*.gif; *.png; *.jpg; *.tif', 'Image Files(*.gif,*.png,*.jpg,*.tif)';'*', 'All files'}, 'File Selector'); 
set(handles.output,'CurrentAxes',handles.imgFixed);
handles.fixPath = strcat(pathname,filename);
hold off;
imshow(handles.fixPath);
hold on;
set( get(handles.imgFixed,'Children'),'ButtonDownFcn', {@imgFixed_ButtonDownFcn,handles});
set( get(handles.imgMoving,'Children'), 'ButtonDownFcn', {@imgMoving_ButtonDownFcn,handles}); 
guidata(hObject,handles);

% --- Executes on button press in uploadMoved.
function uploadMoved_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to uploadMoved (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
[filename,pathname] = uigetfile({'*.gif; *.png; *.jpg; *.tif', 'Image Files (*.gif,*.png,*.jpg,*.tif'; '*', 'All Files'}, 'File Selector');
set(handles.output, 'CurrentAxes', handles.imgMoving);
handles.movePath = strcat(pathname,filename);
hold off;
imshow(handles.movePath);
hold on;
set( get(handles.imgFixed,'Children'), 'ButtonDownFcn', {@imgFixed_ButtonDownFcn,handles});
set( get(handles.imgMoving,'Children'), 'ButtonDownFcn', {@imgMoving_ButtonDownFcn,handles});
guidata(hObject,handles);

% --- Executes on mouse press over axes background.
function imgFixed_ButtonDownFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to imgFixed (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
set(handles.output, 'CurrentAxes', handles.imgFixed);
imshow(handles.imgFixed);

% --- Executes on mouse press over axes background.
function imgMoving_ButtonDownFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to imgMoving (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
set(handles.output, 'CurrentAxes', handles.imgMoving);
imshow(handles.imgMoving);
```

Thank You- I appreciate your time and suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can save a variable in base workspace with [assignin](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/assignin.html) and get her back afterwards with evalin. `assignin('base', 'imgFixed', handles.imgFixed)` - exports handles.imgFixed to the base workspace
2. You can also assign handles.imgFixed to a [global variable](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/global.html). In this way you can access it from every other function. `globale imgFixed; imgFixed = handles.imgFixed;`

But I don't know if I understand your question completely. Why do you want to store these images in the workspace? Whats wrong with the handles to pass the variables around?

Comment: Not satisfied with my answer?